# PHP login cookies security

Tags: php

In most of past questions on SO about security in 'Remember me' feature in login systems, [Persistent Login Cookie Best Practice](http://fishbowl.pastiche.org/2004/01/19/persistent_login_cookie_best_practice/) is suggested.

If I understand correctly, this approach goes like this:

1. If user checks to remember the password, the cookie consisting the username, followed by a separator character, and some large random number should be set. For example:

   `$_COOKIE["login"]; ="adam:8794383bb07608636dab808df6c9e29c"`
2. store username and hash string in database.
3. if both cookies exist, and are mapped to each other in db, the login is accepted.
4. After authentication, remove the random number from cookie, generate a new number and store in cookie. (**Do I need to update this newely generated hashed string in the database as well?**)
5. When user is logged out, current cookie number is also invalidated.(**Should I remove username and the random string from the database?**)

**Is  it all?**

As in my previous question, I was told that if someone can access the cookie, they can easily authenticate. So how does this approach solves that problem?

Many thanks.

Comment: You're basically creating a session system - which is not a problem, just sort of irrelevant to the question. If you want somebody to be remembered, just set an indefinite cookie expiration

Answer (score 2):

Actually, here is what I would recommend. Sample DB Schema

Users:

- user_id
- username
- autologin_hash
- autologin_expire

Process:

1. User clicks remember me
2. Server assigns a unique token and stores it in the database and sends it as a cookie.
3. Server also assigns a fixed expiration date in the autologin_expire field
4. Check to see if the user's cookie equals the one stored with their account on the server AND it has not expired
5. All is good...login, delete the hash, regenerate it, and update the expiration date for the next login

You never, ever want to store usernames or passwords in cookies as they are vulnerable to theft if you are not using SSL. Using a unique hash and clearing it on each login solves these problems: 1) it prevents auth details leakage, 2) it makes a auto login valid only once (cookie cannot be stolen and used again), 3) it enforce a hard expiration date server side which helps prevent abuse, 4) and the long unique ID is hard to impossible to guess so hackers would have to actually steal the cookie to gain access.

Edit: If you want even more security, make a note to clear out the hash if the user changes their password. You don't want valid auto login hashes floating around if the user changed their password out of fear their password was revealed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Why fixed expiration date? Isnt it better to extend the expiration date after authentication, so that the regular visitor do not need to login after a fixed date, thats what i have seen on websites.

Comment: Apologies...I should have explained better. The expire field is for the _new_ hash you created _after_ the user successfully logged in. The rationale for this is you want a limit on the server that the user cannot change. Otherwise, a hacker could take a valid hash and change the cookie expiration date to anything desired. Having a fixed date stops the "I am away on vacation for two weeks and forgot to logout on my office computer" problem.

Answer (score 1):

4). You do need to update the hash, otherwise the person won't be automatically logged in again.

5). You should for clean up, but if it is *invalidated*, your code should not process it as valid.

As for stopping other people from loggin in with that cookie, you could do...

- User agent must be perfect match as well.
- Once logged in, their account is marked *remembered login*. When it comes to changing passwords, making payments, you request their password again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Doesnt the User agent tells only about OS and Browser. If the stolen cookie is used on the computer with same OS and browser version, wouldnt it be same?

Comment: Most sites like Amazon follow this approach. "Remember me" cookies don't allow the user to do important things like checkout without asking the user to login *again* to prove they are that person.

Comment: This system assumes physical security over the computer...auto login systems are vulnerable to start with and should never be relied upon in high security settings.

Comment: @Jay Yes, the same user agent won't provide any security. It is just a simple trick to catch out people who don't have access to your exact string.